# Is it possible to put a label on wxPython gizmos ledctrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

I would like to put a label on wxPython gizmos led, like this.

[image]

But I can't find how to make a label on the led.

My code is like this. I used wxPython StaticText to make the led label, and adjusted the position.

```
import wx.lib.gizmos.ledctrl as led
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title= "LED Test", size = (300,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.myLed = led.LEDNumberCtrl(self.panel, -1, size = (100, 30), pos = (100,50))
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "my LED" , pos=(130,57))
        self.myLed.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        self.label.SetBackgroundColour("green")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

How can I make a gizmos led label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is no, as the question is written.
It is limited to the characters that can be displayed.

> The LEDNumberCtrl can be used to display a series of digits, (plus spaces, colons or dashes,) using a style reminiscent of old-timey segmented digital displays.

```
import wx.lib.gizmos.ledctrl as led
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title= "LED Test", size = (300,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.myLed = led.LEDNumberCtrl(self.panel, -1, size = (200,50), pos = (50,50))
        self.myLed.SetValue(" 22:01")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]